# Spin tensor $S^{\mu \nu}$ and its invariants

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-spin, tensor-calculus, invariants

I am studying a theory in which the spin tensor $S^{\mu \nu}$ has been used for the description of a particle endowed with spin.
I saw that $S^{\mu \nu}$ is a 2-tensor and has the same form of the Faraday tensor, only instead of the $\bar{E}$ and $\bar{B}$ components, there are the electric moment $\bar{p}$ and the magnetic moment $\bar{s}$, respectively.
Knowing the relativistic invariants obtained from the Faraday tensor $F^{\mu \nu}$, namely
\begin{align*}
&F^{\mu \nu}F_{\mu \nu} = 2 \biggl(B^2 - \frac{E^2}{c^2}\biggr)\\
&\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_{\alpha \beta \mu \nu}F^{\alpha \beta}F^{\mu \nu} = - \frac{4}{c}\biggl(\mathbf{B} \cdot \mathbf{E}\biggr),
\end{align*}
then one can deduce that
\begin{align*}
&S^{\mu \nu}S_{\mu \nu} \propto s^2-p^2\\
&\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_{\alpha \beta \mu \nu}S^{\alpha \beta}S^{\mu \nu} \propto \bar{s} \cdot \bar{p}.
\end{align*}
Thus, for example, I can say that if I choose $\bar{s}$ and $\bar{p}$ such that $\bar{s} \cdot \bar{p} = 0$, then this always holds, and moreover, in every frame.
Is it right? Is there anything else to add?